# pandas read_csv file type with double quotes and no-double quotes

Tags: pandas

Hi I have a CSV with this format

Headers: SKU, Product_Name, product_id

3735,[Freebies PC] - Holyshield! Sunscreen Comfort Corrector Serum SPF 50+ PA++++ 5 mL,154674

4568,"Consumables Mika furit 500 gr @250 (16x12x11) packaging  grape, orange)",202737

2403,Laurier Active Day Super Maxi 30 Pcs,8992727002714

I want to be able to read as dataframe in csv, however the problem is that some product names uses "," which is not being able to be read as properly. I checked other sources trying to use sep, however some product names have that others don't. How can i read it properly?

I tried using

```
productList = pd.read_csv('products/products.csv',encoding='utf-8', engine'python)
```

It returns:

| sku | Product_Name | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3735 | [Freebies PC] - Holyshield! Sunscreen Comfort Corrector Serum SPF 50+ PA++++ 5 mL | 154674 |
| 4568,"Consumables Mika furit 500 gr @250 (16x12x11) packaging grape, orange)",202737 | nan | nan |
| 42403 | Laurier Active Day Super Maxi 30 Pcs | 8992727002714 |

expected output is

| sku | Product_Name | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3735 | [Freebies PC] - Holyshield! Sunscreen Comfort Corrector Serum SPF 50+ PA++++ 5 mL | 154674 |
| 4568 | Consumables Mika furit 500 gr @250 (16x12x11) packaging grape, orange) | 202737 |
| 42403 | Laurier Active Day Super Maxi 30 Pcs | 8992727002714 |

How can I do so?

Comment: You can try to replace quote with escape character.  `"` can be replaced with `\"` in csv file

Comment: is there any way around it without manually replacing it? because the file is ingested straigt from bq into python

Comment: yes that would be great.

Comment: would it be better to do a split by "," in sku and return the first and last into the respective columns? To handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content of sample.csv file:

```
product_id,product_name,sku_number
2168,Sanjin Watermelon Frost Obat Sariawan Powder/Bubuk,6903193004029
3798,Common Grounds Cloak & Dagger Instant Coffee 1 Sachets,313166
3799,Common Grounds Ethiopia Guji Instant Coffee 1 Sachets,175744
3580,Emina Glossy Stain Lip Tint Autumn Bell 3gr,8993137707220
"3795,""Hansaplast Kasa Steril - 7,5 x 7,5cm"",8999777016043"
"2997,""Panda GP71 2,5mm"",616920"
```

It seems like output process from db generates error in exported data for some reason. If you are not able to correct the process possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open('sample.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().replace(',""', '","').replace('"",', '","')

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution, but it still returns the same. For all the lines that contains double quotes is being read into the sku only. with product_name and product_id  as blanks

Comment: here's a sample file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VpC5QbjLuH5iU4cB3_lTz5fdn9-fP2iK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hmm. That is something strange. I've used your data as is and the result is on the image above. Ok, I'll think about alternative solution

Comment: @Hal, please take a look at the updated code above

Comment: hi got it, it works just fine. thank you.added ,encoding="utf8" in open, because it returned a  'charmap' codec can't decode byte  error. thank you